# How can I see sdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am using mvc3 to develop an database application and followed the Code-First Tutorial using Entity Framework 4 of msdn site....
I followed all the steps but unable to see the sdf file....
I can perform CRUD operations but can not see the physical database file inside the app_data folder
I also did "Show all file" but still it is not shown in my visual studio explorer...even my App_data folder is empty...

Code inside the web.config file:

```xml
    <add name="Forum1Context"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Forum.sdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe4.0"/>
```

Please Help me!!

Comment: Are you saying you can't see the physical file in windows explorer or you can't see it in Visual Studio? If you're talking about Visual Studio please see the following blog post http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/09/14/visual-studio-tip-show-all-file/

Comment: @heads5150: I did those things but still can't see it in solution explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue. In my case, the name attribute in the add tag was not the same as the name of the class which inherited from DbContext. When I changed the name attribute to match, then I could see the .sdf file, but rows I had inserted previously into the database were lost.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the Database considered your SQL Express rather then the connection string. Fire up SQL Management Studio and check your SQL Express server

Comment: I did that but no such file exists

Comment: its not a file. I was refering to the database beeing created on the local express server, you should be able to see it there with the help of Sql Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

"Data Source=|DataDirectory|Forum.sdf" means Database file is located at "App_Data" folder.
And if you can even perform CRUD operation, Database file should be already there as "App_Data\Forum.sdf". (Please also verify with window explorer).

On Visual Studio, need to enable "Show All Files" on Solution Explorer to view Database file.

[image]

Comment: Thnx for replying...but no luck:(
There is nothng in App_data folder

Comment: @EqEdi Can you see this file with Windows Explorer?

Comment: :No the App_data folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna point out that SQL Express and SqlServer CE are different. SQL Express will need a memory pipe or TCP connection like any other DB server, and the Sql Server CE will automatically create your DB file if doesn't exist at first runtime.

Could it be that you haven't run our app (and EF4.1 code) hence your .sdf file isn't there yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the backslash `\` before `Forum`. I think that will solve it.